# query works with useQuery hook but not with ApolloClient instance

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm running into an issue where running a query with the `useQuery` Apollo hook works fine, but if I use the `useApolloClient` hook to get the instance of `ApolloClient` and then call the client's `query` method, the call fails with the error `Error: query option is required. You must specify your GraphQL document in the query option.`

My code more or less looks like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
import { useQuery, useApolloClient } from '@apollo/react-hooks'

const MyComponent = props => {

  const QUERY = gql`
    query MyPersonSearch ( $after: String, $filter: PersonFilter, $first: Int ) {
      people: people ( after: $after, filter: $filter, first: $first ) {
        totalCount
        pageInfo {
          endCursor
          hasNextPage
        }
        edges {
          node {
            firstName
            lastName
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `

  const queryVars = cursor => { after: cursor, ...otherQueryVars }

  // This works
  const { loading, error, data, fetchMore } = useQuery(
    QUERY, { variables: queryVars( ... ) }
  )

  // This doesn't work
  const client = useApolloClient()
  const fetchPages = async () => {
    const { data } = await client.query( QUERY, { variables: queryVars( ... ) } )
  }


  ...
}
```

Any idea what's going on here? The error message is a little vague, but I'm assuming it means that `client.query()` expects a `DocumentNode` as its first parameter, and the return type of `gql` is `any`...but then again, if this were true, I would expect `useQuery` to fail too, since it also expects the query to be a `DocumentNode`.

Answer (score 0):

Welp, turns out the syntax is not the same. `client.query()` expects a sole `QueryOptions` parameter, whereas `useQuery` can take the query as the first parameter, and an optional `QueryOptions` second parameter.